# Get report for a single node/certname via PuppetDB API using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, puppet

So the API endpoint "**reports**" does provide this information using curl as below:

```
curl -X GET http://puppetserver:8080/pdb/query/v4/reports -d 'limit=1' -d 'query=["=", "certname", "node.fqdn"]'
```

But as I am trying to achieve this using javascript in React, that doesn't seem to work.

Something like this:

```
let puppetdbUrl = 'http://puppetserver:8080/pdb/query/v4/reports';
getReport = () => {
        axios.get(puppetdbUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            params: {
                'certname': 'node.fqdn'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({resultReport: response});
            console.log(this.state.resultReport);
        })
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
400 (Bad Request). Unsupported query parameter 'certname'.
```

The document for puppetdb API does have these query parameters:
https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/5.2/api/query/v4/reports.html. Can someone please help?

I get the same error while trying to achieve the same thing using a rest client.